# Change /index.php?route=affiliate/account to /affiliate OpenCart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, seo, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm trying to turn

**`http://www.example.com/index.php?route=affiliate/login`**

into just

**`http://www.example.com/affiliate`**

I know that I need to edit the **`seo_url.php`** file and put **`affiliate/login`** into the url_alias table of mysql database but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried downloading **`vq2-catalog_controller_common_seo_url.php`** from http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=112&t=115293&p=458532#p458532 but it broke my site so had to restore the backed up **`seo_url.php`** file.

Comment: share you code whatever you have done ...

Comment: May be this can help http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=32872#p164179.

Comment: Hello I have since installed an extension which looked like it was going to help solve this problem however it has resulted in my website going down please see new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945084/opencart-site-is-down-after-installing-extension

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use htaccess for the url by creating new rewrite rules

## NEW REWRITE RULES

RewriteRule   ^affiliate/?$    index.php?route=affiliate/login [L]  #Affiliate page

and give a url http://www.example.com/affiliate in a link to click